# How to use combo box in c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have no idea where to start. i tried DataTable but it didn't work.(This is an easy question :) )

I tried everything

```
{
    var test = new DataTable();
    test.Columns.Add("test");
    test.TableName = "test";
    test.Columns.Add("test");

    comboBox1.DataSource = test.XXXX ;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you mean winforms, something like:

```
    DataTable test = new DataTable();
    test.TableName = "test";
    test.Columns.Add("foo", typeof(string));
    test.Columns.Add("bar", typeof(int));
    test.Rows.Add("abc", 123);
    test.Rows.Add("def", 456);

    ComboBox cbo = new ComboBox();
    cbo.DataSource = test;
    cbo.DisplayMember = "foo";
    cbo.ValueMember = "bar";

    Form form = new Form();
    form.Controls.Add(cbo);
    Application.Run(form);
```

(in particular, `SelectedValue` should give you the `123` and `456` - useful for ids, etc)

Answer (score 2):

[ComboBox.Items property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx), unless you want data from a database or something.

Answer (score 2):

```
  DataTable dt=new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Col1",typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("Col2",typeof(String));
  dt.Rows.Add(1,"A");
  dt.Rows.Add(2,"B");

   comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
   comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Col2";
   comboBox1.ValueMember = "Col1";
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the 'DataItemField' and 'DataValueField' to the appropriate column names in your datatable.