# How can I insert products into combo box by loading form

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I am new to C# and I have one problem With XML file. My code is below

```
 <root>
<product category="Soaps">
    <product type="Washing"></product>
    <product type="Bathing"></product>
</product>
<product category="ThoothPaste">
    <product type="ThoothPaste"></product>
</product>
<product category="Biscuits">
  <product type="Parle"></product>
  <product type="Marrie"></product>
  <product type="Britania"></product>
</product>
   </root>
```

I want when I load the form, product type attributes should be inserted into my combobox. I tried the blow code but I did not get expected result.

Can any one provide solution?

```
  private void Admin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       ds.ReadXml(strpath + "Products.xml");
       dgvProducts.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];



       xdoc.Load(strpath + "list.xml");
      // MessageBox.Show("Test231");
       XmlNodeList nodeList = xdoc.SelectNodes("//product");
      // MessageBox.Show("Test");
       foreach (XmlNodeList node in nodeList)
       {
           cmbBox.Items.Add(node.innerText)
       }


    }
```

Comment: A quick glance at the "related questions" list gives you this question, whose answers should tell you all you need to know... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304416/how-to-use-combo-box-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above posted solution would not work as it would throw a null reference exception use the sample Linq-xml code below

```
XElement xElement = XElement.Load(@"XMLFile1.xml");

            var producttypes = from ptypes in
                                   xElement.Descendants("product")
                               let xAttribute = ptypes.Attribute("type")
                               where xAttribute != null
                               select xAttribute.Value;

            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var ptypes in producttypes)
            {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(ptypes);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **LINQ2XML**..Its very simple and a complete replacement to other XML API's

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load(strpath + "Products.xml");

foreach (string type in doc.Descendants("product").Select(x=>x.Attribute("type").Value).ToList<string>())
       {
           cmbBox.Items.Add(type)
       }
```

Comment: Here I got exception object reference not set tp an instance of an object